# I'm trying to create scim integration. In Azure databricks email attribute is missing

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-databricks, scim2

I would like to test my scim integration with Azure Active Directory.
I created provisioning in DataBricks, but the list of attributes is missing email.
How do I add it?

**Update after the answer was accepted:** I was trying to use DataBricks in order to test my SCIM implementation for Azure. The right way is to create an app, edit mappings according to the needs and submit the app to the Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear. How are you trying to provision from Azure AD to Databricks? You should be adding the Databricks Enterprise App from the gallery (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/scim/aad) for exact steps). The gallery app has the mappings preconfigured in a way tailored to Databricks - specifically, it's set to not attempt updates on userName or email attributes as both are immutable in the Databricks system.